# Is there any documentation to how to write custom Xcode Project Templates?

Tags: xcode

Is there any documentation available on how to write plugins for the xcode? I have googled the subject but i was not able to find any reasonable answer, so i was wondering if someone here knows the resources which can help.

In general i am looking for how i can create "Project Templates" for different kind of languages or framework. In other words creating "Custom Project Templates".

Comment: Maybe you should add what's missing in docs like these: http://www.turkeysheartrhinos.com/?p=8 - http://guides.macrumors.com/Creating_Xcode_project_templates to make it easier to show you the right stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create project templates without needing a plug-in. Just look in `/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/` and follow the same format (you can add yours in your user’s app support directory).

Answer (score 5):

"No" is an answer, whether you like it or not. Apple doesn't document this.

Answer (score 0):

http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-plugin-interface/

Maybe…but not from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively write an AppleScript, perl, python or bash script that can be executed from Xcode.

The scripts are listed in the Script menu (between Window and Help), which also offers a script editor ("Edit User Scripts...").

Answer (score -1):

You can use this template which is a well researched one available in the market.

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-boilerplate-and-template/1597